# Python tkinter - what is the difference between a widgets padx and pack-methods ipadx

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I try to understand the difference between padx of a widget and ipadx of the pack method for that widget.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

Button(window, text="aaaaaa", padx=50).pack()
Button(window, text="aaaaaa").pack(ipadx=50)

window.mainloop()
```

On my system the second button is two pixels wider. Shouldn't both buttons have the same width?

Initially I thought, the difference to be related to the border of the buttons but regardless of border_width, the difference of two pixels remains.

I understand the difference between ipadx and padx within pack() but expected ipadx of pack to be equivalent to padx of the widget.

Comment: Button(window, text="aaaaaa").pack(padx=50, pady=50)
Button(window, text="aaaaaa").pack(ipadx=50, ipady=50 )

Comment: It is because `padx=1` by default for `Button` widget. So there are total 51 pixels in horizontal paddings inside both sides for the second button.

Comment: That seems to be the answer, I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No clue how to mark acw1668's comment as the expected answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the default value of `padx` option is 1 for a `Button` widget, that is why  the second button is 2 pixels wider than the first button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 2nd button will be 2px wider.

Because padx is meant for spacing outside the widget horizontally.
And ipadx is meant for spacing inside the widget horizontally.
Logic is same in the case of pady and ipady as well.

If you want to give your preferred space between the letters(say 'submit') in the button and the buttom border, you should use ipadx and ipad y.

If you want to give space between the current button and the previous/next button, you should use padx if packed horizontally(or pady if packed vertically)

While providing ipadx, you don't need to provide border-width. Because the border width is automatically decided by the length of the font, font-size and ipadx.

If you want the space should be same between two widgets and pady, you should give the same value to padx and ipadx if packed horizontally.

If packed vertically, you should give the same value to pady and ipady

Comment: *"ipadx is meant for spacing inside the widget vertically"* - isn't it horizontally (`ipadx` = internal padding x-axis)?

Comment: typed by oversight. It's horizontally

Comment: Now edited after seeing your comment. Please see now.

Comment: You refer to the difference between padx and ipadx. My question was regarding the internal spacing via padx of the button and ipadx of the pack method for the button. Both affect the same padding of the button. As pointed out by acw1668, they both work in combination and the default for padx of the button is 1, hence 2 additional pixels...